# unable to obtain matrix on the front-end, console, log corresponding content displayed unrecognized

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

The backend returns the transposed matrix as a response, but the idea console did not use an error or null pointer exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXTwQ.png)

```
   var rowCount = parseInt($('#row-count').val());
        var colCount = parseInt($('#col-count').val());
        console.log(rowCount)

        var tableHtml = `<table>`;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
          tableHtml += '<tr>';
          for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            $('#col-count')
            tableHtml += `<td><input type="text" name="matrix[${i}][${j}]}"></td>`;
            // tableHtml += '<td><input type="text" name="matrix['+i+']['+j+']"></td>';
            console.log(document.getElementsByName(`matrix[${i}][${j}]`));
            console.log($('input[name="matrix[' + i + '][' + j + ']"]').val());
          }
          tableHtml += '</tr>';
        }
        tableHtml += '</table>';[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g49J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMGv3.png)
```

The backend returns the transposed matrix as a response, but the idea console did not use an error or null pointer exception